# How to create weekly totals using start and end dates in R

Tags: r, date, count, dplyr

I have a dataframe with 3 year data from workers: The variables d_start and d_end, indicate the date the worker started working and finished respectively.

I need to obtain weekly counts of active workers, starting from year1. It is posible for a worker to join in a project before year1.

I started by creating a vector V = (1:52) with the number of weeks in a year and for every row, to build a vector with the corresponding week, using

```
seq("d_start", "d_end", by= "week")
```

then to compare with the vector V and sum in the corresponding week, but it didn´t work.

That is what I have (Real data)

```
d_start     d_end
2015/01/17  2018/03/22
2016/03/01  2016/10/02 
2017/01/17  2018/03/19
2017/01/17  2018/03/25
2016/02/01  2016/04/30
.           .
.           .
.           .
```

That is what I need, (it is an example)

```
year  week   count
2016  1       20
2016  2       28
.     .       . 
.     .       . 
.     .       . 
2016  52      25
2017  1       22
2017  3       14
2017  4        8
.     .       . 
.     .       . 
.     .       . 
2017 52       14
2018  1       25
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df` is just your dataframe. `mutate` uses the `year` and `week` functions from `lubridate` to extract years and weeks. Then the rest is pretty straightforward.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df = df %>% mutate(year = year(d_start), week = week(d_start)) %>% 
  group_by(year, week) %>% summarise(count = n())
```

EDIT: Misinterpreted question. Here is a (messy) solution.

```
df = data.frame(d_start = as.Date(c('2015/01/17','2016/03/01','2017/01/17','2017/01/17','2016/02/01')),
                d_end = as.Date(c('2018/03/22','2016/10/02','2018/03/19','2018/03/25','2016/04/30')))
df2 = data.frame(Date = seq(min(df$d_start), max(df$d_end), by = 'week')) %>% 
  mutate(year = year(Date), week = week(Date), count = 0) %>% select(-Date)
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]) {
  x = df[i,]
  interval = seq(x$d_start, x$d_end, by = 'week')
  interval = paste(year(interval), week(interval), sep = '-')
  df2[paste(df2$year, df2$week, sep = '-') %in% interval,]$count = df2[paste(df2$year, df2$week, sep = '-') %in% interval,]$count + 1
}
```

First I init the result dataframe `df2` with year and week, and set count to 0. Then I loop over `df`, calculate the year(s) and weeks worker `i` is active, and increment `df2$count` for the matching year(s) and weeks.

Comment: Spinodal: *I really thank you!* but let me ask you a question about the code with an example. Suppose I have two workers: the two started the first week of january, but only one of them worked til last week of december. So, the final result will be a weekly count of two until midyear  and 1 after that. Does this code do that? I expect to have a vector of length 52 with the first half equal 2 and the second half equal 1. <br/> Your code produced only one line.

Comment: I think your code counts the number of rows (workers) started in the same week. But I need to know "how many workers were active in a given week." Thats why I have d_start and d_end for every worker. As I said. for year 1, for example, I will have a vector of lenght 52 with the number of active worker for every week.

Comment: sorry about that, misinterpreted you. I edited in a messy solution to your problem

Comment: +1 Great! That´s what i was looking for! Simply awesome! Thanks a lot **spinodal** ! Now I can use it to develop my models!

Comment: glad it worked! sorry I didn't get it the first time ^.^